# Django: How/Where to store a value for a session without unnecessary DB hits

Tags: database, django, performance, django-models

I have an extended userprofile with [AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-profile-module).

I would like to set a `user.is_guru()` method similar to `user.is_active()`. This would results for al views (or rather templates) to e.g. disable/enable certain user messages, displaying of widgets, etc. The boolean is stored in the extended user profile model, but I want to avoid hitting the DB for every view.

So the questions is .. Do I use a context_processor, a template tag, session_dict or what have you to, possible cached, store this info for the duration of the users visit.

Note: I dont have performance issues, so it's definitely filed under premature optimization. I just want to avoid generating extra work in the future :).

Any pointers are very welcome.

Thanx and greetz!

Gerard.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can use a [cache session backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) (beware that data might not persist, store the value somewhere else).

I really wouldn't be worried about avoiding hitting the database at an early stage, it's not difficult to rewire well written django applications.